# Default values of pf.conf set parameters

Tags: openbsd, pf

I want to learn default values of these parameters, I read the manual of pf.conf but couldn't find, could you help?

```
set limit states
set limit src-nodes
set timeout tcp.first
set timeout tcp.established
set timeout tcp.closing
set timeout tcp.finwait
set timeout tcp.closed
set timeout udp.first
set timeout udp.multiple
set timeout udp.single
set timeout adaptive.start
set timeout adaptive.end
set timeout interval
```

Answer (score 5):

To list all values, try

```
pfctl -s all
```

To list only the limits you requested, try

```
pfctl -s memory
```

To list only the timeouts you requested, try

```
pfctl -s timeouts
```

Out of the curiosity: Are you sure you need to adjust those values? Are you sure you can outsmart the default values, if merely listing the values is not familiar to you?

Answer (score 2):

Many if of the default settings you want to know can be found in the [PF FAQ's chapter on Runtime Options](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/options.html)